# How to not lose hasMany changes on Ember query?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember.js-2

In my application, I search for documents with query.
Then I edit one attribute in a single document, and then I call search query again.

Result is OK, I see document still in a dirty state with changed attribute.

Then I again pick one of documents and edit its `hasMany` relation (from 2 items to 4 items). And then I call search query again.
Result is NOT OK, hasMany relation change is lost/disposed/rollbacked.

Is there a way so Ember query (i guess it's some Ember internal reload) does not rollback not saved relation changes ?

I am using Ember 2.9.1

For now i have no other way than prohibit any filter query actions or route actions anything that could call query again, since that would cause lost data that user set.

Answer (score 1):

Ember's `store.query` method always refetches the models from the backend (unlike the `find*` methods). With a query, it's the only way to make sure you have the most up-to-date data (and that the models loaded into the store are still valid). Even in your instance, you may run into unexpected results if you change the data such that it no longer meets your query criteria.

If you would like to keep edits around between queries, I would recommend making a copy of all models which are dirty (check the [`hasDirtyAttributes`](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_hasDirtyAttributes) attribute). You can gather them with `peekAll`. Once copied, you can then make the `query` and patch the records by ID. Perhaps by using `Ember.assign`.

Even using that method, I would still think that you will get into trouble tracking the changes and making sure the records stay consistent with your query. Like what do you if that record wasn't returned (deleted on the server or no longer meets your criteria)? Do you drop your edits? What if you have a conflict between the data from the server and your local version (e.g. another user patched the `hasMany` relationship that the other user is now querying and modifying)?

[ember-changeset](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-changeset) seems like it could be useful here. However, it's not obvious how to get a `ChangeSet` to apply to a new instance of the same model. Though it may be possible to keep a `snapshot` and match them up manually. However, you still run into data consistency issues.

Comment: Best would be if query did not updated my edited tasks at all. 

User will edit task departments (still not save). Then he will click to see unfinished tasks where edited one is also between them and BOOM departments roll back. 

If it got deleted in mean time, while saving api will react on this. If it got changed, well that can happen any time in any web application even milisecond after deprartmens changed by user, its web, api will deal with overriding last or conflict solution.

When calling reload on model relations are not lost but, with query they are :(